# Which folder I should backup?

Tags: linux, ovh

I have server on ubuntu 22.04/OVH. I have my main files in home. I using docker, and backup every day all docker-compose file and data folder.

I want also backup my server setup, nginx configuration, ssh-key etc, which folder I should add, or maybe backup all partition by clonezilla etc?

Answer (score 1):

Let the [file-hierarchy(7)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/file-hierarchy.7.html) man page guide you. If this hierarchy is followed, all the settings should be under `/etc/`. On the other hand, you should never need to backup anything under, e.g., the section "vendor-supplied operating system resources" (`/usr/` & `/lib/`)  as they can be reinstalled, nor the section "virtual kernel and API file systems" (`/dev/`, `/proc/` & `/sys/`).